# Remove dependency from package.json before npm install task

Tags: azure, npm, azure-pipelines

I need to exclude a specific dependency when running the `npm install` task in the Azure pipeline and then install that package by itself after in order to resolve some dependency issues I'm running into.

I've tried creating a custom npm task to uninstall the specific dependency before running the npm install task but I don't think that actually removes it from the package.json so when the install task is ran that is still getting included. Here's a snippet from my yml file:

```
    - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: "custom"
      customCommand: "uninstall package_name"
      customRegistry: "useFeed"
      customFeed: ""

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: "install"
      customRegistry: "useFeed"
      customFeed: ""
    displayName: "Install Feed"

  - script: |
      npm install
    displayName: "npm install"

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: "custom"
      customCommand: "install package_name"
      customRegistry: "useFeed"
      customFeed: ""

  - script: |
      npm run build
      CI=true npm test
```

The error happens when I try to `npm run build` in order for the pipeline to perform the tests. For reference, this is the error I am trying to resolve [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to resolve this package versioning issue locally to get both babel-eslint versions matching

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).